# Ag-Grid: How to highlight a specific row on click on the row or any cell of that row, without selecting the row?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid and have checkboxes to select the row.
What I want to do is, any time the user clicks on any row or cell of that row, the complete row gets highlighted, **without** selecting the row.

Comment: Any imperative method of getting row dom node onRowClicked event and adding style to it is also acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

I think your best solution would be to use the `onCellClicked` callback, and set the row as selected. Take a look at this code:

```
<AgGridReact
    onCellClicked={this.cellClicked}
    columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
    rowData={this.state.rowData}
/>
```

And your callback method:

```
cellClicked(params) {
    params.node.setSelected(true)
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-react-hello-world-tbewq4) is a StackBlitz example for you.

Answer (score 0):

we are using **onRowClicked** property to get **node** value. Using node value we are setting **setSeleted** to true to highlighted row in the following way.

```
const rowDataSelection = useCallback(value => {
    value.node.setSelected(true)  // this will be used to highlight the row
    setRowData({rowData: value.data || {}})
})

<Grid
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    defaultColDef={{ resizable: true, sortable: true }}
    licenseKey={'abc-123'}
    onGridReady={onGridReadyAPI}
    autoGroupColumnDef={autoGroupColumnDef}
    treeData={true}
    groupDefaultExpanded={-1}
    onRowClicked={rowDataSelection}
    getDataPath={getDataPath}
    rowData={searchData}
    ref={gridRef}
    overlayNoRowsTemplate={'No results found. Please refine your search criteria.'}
/>
```